# Auto Scrolling li with 4 limited li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am currently doing this design, [click here](http://icodeph.com/ad/latest.html)

I am trying to imitate the same section as this, [click here](https://www.euromooncasino.com/?lang=en)

```
<div class="latest-winners-container">
  <h3 class="header">Latest Winners</h3>
    <div style="height: 205px; overflow: hidden;">
      <ul class="latest-winners" data-items-per-page="4" data-delay="4" data-animation-speed="1000" data-template="latest_winners_lobby" style="position: relative;">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Do you guys have any idea how I can do the same behavior?

Comment: try using scrolltop

Comment: I've already tried. Nothing's happening

Comment: Works for me. I put an `id=box` on your `overflow: hidden` div then I just used `document.getElementById('box').scrollTop = "700";` and it's moving for me. Not sure you're tlaking about.

Comment: oh gosh, thanks a lot! Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: I'll put it as answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the div an id then just use:

```
document.getElementById(id).scrollTop = number;
```

where `id` is the id of your div and `number` is an int

Comment: One thing, how can I scroll on a specific <li>

Comment: $('.scrolling').animate({

       scrollTop: $('.scrolling li:nth-child(4)').position().top
   }, 'slow');

I used this, but I need it to go to every 4th li

Comment: I can't actually use jquery on your site since it's blocked, but I'm guessing you would need a foreach on that thing.

Comment: hm, I see.. I'll try that thanks

Comment: by that thing I mean `$('.scrolling li:nth-child(4)').position().top` as I think it would return an array.